# Anaconda install - Immediate error - conda.exe: not found

Tags: installation, anaconda, alpine-linux, failed-installation

I installing Anaconda on Alpine Linux.
I am new to linux and anaconda and etc.
I am follow https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/linux/ recomendations.
Downloaded Anaconda3-2023.09-0-Linux-x86_64.sh, checked MD5 - ok.
Run it, agreed with license and install location.
Got error: **line 348: /home/username/anaconda3/conda.exe: not found**

```
[/home/username/anaconda3] >>>
PREFIX=/home/username/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
./Anaconda3-2023.09-0-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 348: /home/username/anaconda3/conda.exe: not found
alpine:~$
```

Python & PIP are installed:

```
alpine:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.6
alpine:~$ pip --version
pip 23.3.1 from /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
alpine:~$
```

I tried to run scrip under user and under root - got same error.
I excpect script to run without hindrance, but...
Cannot guess how to fix it, even general direction.

Advice me, please?